# Why is this map a unitary?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

Consider following theorem from Murphy's '$C^*$-algebras and operator theory'

[image]

The proof says that if $p=1$, then the assertion that the map $H \to \bigoplus_\lambda p_\lambda(H)$ is a unitary is clear.

I don't see why this is true though. To show it is a unitary, it suffices to show that it is isometric and surjective. I can see it is isometric, but don't see why it should be surjective.

I tried the following:

Let $(p_\lambda(x_\lambda))_\lambda \in \bigoplus_\lambda p_\lambda(H)$. I guess we must take something like $x= \sum_\lambda x_\lambda$ and show that this still gets mapped to what we want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is obviously surjective.

Let $y\in \oplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda} p_{\lambda}(H)$ and define $x=\sum_{\lambda} y_{\lambda}$. We just need to argue that $p_{\lambda}(x)=y_{\lambda}$. Since, the $p_{\lambda}$ are orthogonal, we see that $p_{\lambda}(y_{\lambda'})=0$ for $\lambda\neq \lambda'$ and thus, by continuity

$$
p_{\lambda}(x)=\sum_{\lambda'}p_{\lambda}(y_{\lambda'})=p_{\lambda}(y_{\lambda})=y_{\lambda}
$$
since $p_{\lambda}$ is a projection. This proves the desired.

Comment: Why is $\sum_\lambda y_\lambda$ well-defined?

Comment: Ah yes, since it is square summable!

Comment: Yes, simply because the norm of $x$ is in $H$ is clearly the norm of $y$ in $\oplus_{\lambda\in \Lambda} p_{\lambda}(H)$.

Comment: See here for a follow-up question if you are interested/have time: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777049/show-that-x-sum-i-in-i-x-i-converges-in-a-banach-space

Comment: Looks fine. I'd probably just pick a finite set $F$ such that $\sum_{i\not\in F} \|x_i\|^2<\varepsilon/2$ and then bound $\|\sum_{k\in K} x_k-\sum_{l\in L} x_l\|^2\leq 2\sum_{i\not \in F} \|x_i\|^2$ if  $F\subseteq K\cap L$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!