# Show that $x = \sum_{i \in I} x_i$ converges in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $(H_i)_{i \in I}$ is a collection of closed **orthogonal** subspaces of the Hilbert space $H$. Suppose that $\sum_{i \in I} \Vert x_i \Vert^2 < \infty$. Prove that $\sum_{i \in I} x_i$ converges in $H$.

Here $\sum_{i \in I} x_i$ is the norm-limit of the net $(\sum_{i \in J} x_i)$ where $J$ ranges over all finite subsets of $I$, ordered by inclusion.

**Attempt**:

It suffices to check that $(\sum_{i \in J} x_i)_J$ is a Cauchy net in $H$. So, let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\sum_{i \in I} \Vert x_i \Vert^2 < \infty$, we have that $(\sum_{i \in J} \Vert x_i \Vert^2)_J$ is a Cauchy net.  Thus, there is a finite subset $J_0 \subseteq I$ such that if $K,L$ are finite subsets of $I$ containing $J_0$, then $$\sum_{K \triangle L} \Vert x_i \Vert^2 =  |\sum_K \Vert x_i \Vert^2 - \sum_L \Vert x_i\Vert^2 | < \epsilon$$

Here $K \triangle L = (K \setminus L) \cup (L \setminus K)$ is the symmetric difference.

Consequently, for $K,L$ as above
$$\Vert \sum_K x_i - \sum_L x_i \Vert ^2 = \Vert \sum_{K\triangle L} x_i \Vert ^2 = \sum_{K \triangle L} 
 \Vert x_i \Vert^2 < \epsilon$$

Hence $(\sum_{i \in J} x_i)_J$ is a Cauchy net in $H$ and we are done.

Is this correct? I think the step with the $\triangle $ might be flawed.

Comment: The argument "Since $\sum_{i\in I}||x_{i}||^{2}<\infty$, we have
that ($\sum_{i\in J}||x_{i}||)_{J}$ is a Cauchy net'' is wrong.
For example, we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty$
but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\infty$.

Comment: The step with $\triangle$ is indeed false. It's not true that 
$$
\| \sum_{K}x_i-\sum_{L}x_i \| = \| \sum_{K \triangle L} x_i \|.
$$ 
For example, say $K=\{1,2\}$ and $L=\{2,3\}$. Then, $\| \sum_{K}x_i-\sum_{L}x_i \| = \| x_1-x_3\|$, whereas  $\| \sum_{K \triangle L} x_i \|=\|x_1+x_3\|$.

Comment: The $(H_i)$ don't seem to play a role in the statement. Why do you even mention them?

Comment: I guess you forgot to mention that $x_i \in H_i$. It would also be sufficient to assume that the $x_i$ are pairwise orthogonal.

Comment: Do you also need a proof that Cauchy nets converge or is that already known to you? See Danny Pak-Keung Chan's comment to my answer.

Comment: I know that Banach spaces are complete topological vector spaces, i.e. all Cauchynets converge.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín It is true under the (unmentioned) assumption $x_i \in H_i$.

Comment: @PaulFrost that's right! However, even with orthogonality, it's not always true that 
$$
\left| \sum_{K}\|x_i\|^2-\sum_{L}\|x_i\|^2\right|= \sum_{K \triangle L}\|x_i\|^2
$$

Comment: @Alonso Yes, it is false in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot to mention that $x_i \in H_i$. It would also be sufficient to assume that the $x_i$ are pairwise orthogonal. This implies that for finite $A \subset I$ and $\sigma(i) = \pm 1$
$$\Vert \sum_A  (-1)^{\sigma(i)}x_i \Vert^2 =  \left\langle \sum_A (-1)^{\sigma(i)}x_i ,\sum_A (-1)^{\sigma(i)}x_i  \right\rangle = \sum_{i \in A, j \in A} (-1)^{\sigma(i)}(-1)^{\sigma(j)}\langle x_i,x_j\rangle\\ = \sum_{A} (-1)^{\sigma(i)}(-1)^{\sigma(i)}\lVert x_i \rVert^2 = \sum_{A} \lVert x_i \rVert^2 . $$
It is in general not true that
$$\sum_{K \triangle L} \Vert x_i \Vert^2 =  \left|\sum_K \Vert x_i \Vert^2 - \sum_L \Vert x_i\Vert^2 \right| .$$
Anyway, we do not need it. Your equation
$$\Vert \sum_K x_i - \sum_L x_i \Vert ^2 = \Vert \sum_{K\triangle L} x_i \Vert ^2 = \sum_{K \triangle L} \Vert x_i \Vert^2 \tag{1}$$
is true, but requires a proof which you have not given and moreover needs an explanation what it has to with $(\sum_J x_i)$ being a Cauchy net.

Let us therefore start at the beginning. What we know is that
$$\left|\sum_A \Vert x_i \Vert^2 - \sum_B \Vert x_i\Vert^2 \right| < \epsilon $$
for finite $A, B \supset J_0$. Thus in particular for any finite set $F \subset I$ such that $F \cap J_0 = \emptyset$ we may take $A = J_0 \cup F$ and $B = J_0$ and obtain
$$\sum_{F}\Vert x_i \Vert^2 < \epsilon . \tag{2}$$

For finite $K, L \supset J_0$ we therefore get
$$\Vert \sum_K x_i - \sum_L x_i \Vert ^2 = \Vert \sum_{K \triangle L} (-1)^{\sigma(i)}x_i  \Vert ^2 = \sum_{K \triangle L} \Vert x_i \Vert^2  < \epsilon$$
because $K \triangle L$ is disjoint from $J_0$. Note that in $(1)$ the middle term $\Vert \sum_{K\triangle L} x_i \Vert ^2$ is irrelevant.

Comment: One fact needs justification: For the completeness of Hilbert space, it is usually defined as "Every Cauchy sequence is convergent" but not "Every Cauchy net is convergent". The latter fact needs a proof.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan You are right, but I did what the OP wanted to prove: That we have a Cauchy net in $H$. But I shall ask the OP whether he also needs a proof for the convergence of Cauchy nets.

Answer (score 5):

Some mistakes have already been pointed out. So I will give  a valid proof.

$ \sum \|x_i\|^{2} <\infty$ implies that $x_i=0$ for al but countably many $i$. Hence the result reduces to the case of  countable family $(H_i)_{i \geq 1}$.

In this case $\|\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} x_i\|^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} \|x_i\|^{2}$ by orthogonality and hence $(\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} x_i)$ is Cauchy. This finishes the proof since $H$ is compete.

[ If $\|x_{i_j}\| >\frac  1 n$ for $j=1,2,..,N$ then $\sum \|x_i||^{2} \geq \frac N {n^{2}}$ proving that $N \leq \sum \|x_i\|^{2}n^{2}$. This proves that there are only finitely many $x_i$'s with $\|x_i\| >\frac  1 n$  and taking union over $n$ we see that there are at most  countably many $i$'s with $\|x_i\|>0$].

Comment: You proved that the ordered sum converges, but this does not imply the unordered sum converges.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let us clarify the meaning of the symbol $\sum_{i\in I}x_{i}$.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the collection of all finite subsets of $I$.
Then $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq)$ is a directed system in the following
sense:

(1) For any $J\in\mathcal{C}$, $J\subseteq J$,

(2) For any $J_{1},J_{2},J_{3}\in\mathcal{C}$, if $J_{1}\subseteq J_{2}$
and $J_{2}\subseteq J_{3}$, then $J_{1}\subseteq J_{3}$,

(3) For any $J_{1},J_{2}\in\mathcal{C}$, there exists $J_{3}\in\mathcal{C}$
such that $J_{1}\subseteq J_{3}$ and $J_{2}\subseteq J_{3}$.

---

Define a map $\theta:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow H$ by $\theta(J)=\sum_{j\in J}x_{j}$.
Then $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq,\theta)$ is a net on the Hilbert space.
We say that the net converges to some $x\in H$ if for any $\varepsilon>0$,
there exists $J_{0}\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $||\theta(J)-x||<\varepsilon$
whenever $J_{0}\subseteq J$. If such $x$ exists, it is unique (because
the norm topology on $H$ is Hausdorff) and we denote it by the symbol
$\sum_{i\in I}x_{i}$.

---

Go back to our question. Let $I_{0}=\{i\in I\mid x_{i}\neq0\}$. We
firstly show that $I_{0}$ is at most countable. Prove by contradiction.
Suppose that $I_{0}$ in uncountable. Observe that $I_{0}=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{i\in I\mid||x_{i}||^{2}>\frac{1}{n}\},$
so there exists $n$ such that $\{i\in I\mid||x_{i}||^{2}>\frac{1}{n}\}$
is uncountable. Denote $I'=\{i\in I\mid||x_{i}||^{2}>\frac{1}{n}\}$,
then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i\in I}||x_{i}||^{2} & \geq & \sum_{i\in I'}||x_{i}||^{2}\\
 & \geq & \sum_{i\in I'}\frac{1}{n}\\
 & = & \infty,
\end{eqnarray*}
which is a contradiction. In another word, in the formal sum $\sum_{i\in I}x_{i}$,
there are at most countably many of terms are non-zero. Fix an enumeration
for $I_{0}$, for example, $I_{0}=\{i_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
(Note that if $I_{0}$ is a finite set, we simply have set $x=\sum_{i\in I_{0}}x_{i}$
and prove that $x$ is the limit of the net $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq,\theta)$
defined in above. We skip this simple case.)

For each $n$, define $s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{i_{k}}$. We go to show
that $(s_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H$. Note that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}||x_{i_{k}}||^{2}=\sum_{i\in I}||x_{i}||^{2}<\infty$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, then there exists $N$ such that for
any $N\leq m<n$, we have $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}||x_{i_{k}}||^{2}<\varepsilon$.
Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary such that $N\leq m<n$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & ||s_{n}-s_{m}||^{2}\\
 & = & \sum_{k=m+1}^{n}||x_{i_{k}}||^{2}\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
By completeness of $H$, there exists $x\in H$ such that $s_{n}\rightarrow x$.
Finally we go to show that the net $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq,\theta)$
converges to $x$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$
such that $\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}||x_{i_{k}}||^{2}\leq\varepsilon^{2}$.
For any $n>N$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & ||s_{N}-s_{n}||^{2}\\
 & = & \sum_{k=N+1}^{n}||x_{i_{k}}||^{2}\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}||x_{i_{k}}||^{2}\\
 & \leq & \varepsilon^{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have $||s_{N}-x||\leq\varepsilon$.
Define $J_{0}=\{i_{1},i_{2},\ldots,i_{N}\}\in\mathcal{C}$. Let $J\in\mathcal{C}$
be such that $J_{0}\subseteq J$. We have estimation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & ||\theta(J)-x||\\
 & \leq & ||\theta(J)-\theta(J_{0})||+||\theta(J_{0})-x||\\
 & = & ||s_{N}-x||+||\theta(J)-\theta(J_{0})||.
\end{eqnarray*}
Observe that $\theta(J)-\theta(J_{0})=\sum_{i\in I_{0}\cap(J\setminus J_{0})}x_{i}$.
Hence,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & ||\theta(J)-\theta(J_{0})||^{2}\\
 & = & \sum_{i\in I_{0}\cap(J\setminus J_{0})}||x_{i}||^{2}\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}||x_{i_{k}}||^{2}\\
 & \leq & \varepsilon^{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is now clear that $||\theta(J)-x||\leq2\varepsilon$. That is,
the net $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq,\theta)$ converges to $x$.

---

---

An important application for orthonormal base and Fourier expansion:
Let $\{e_{i}\mid i\in I\}$ be an orthonormal base for $H$. For each
$i\in I$, let $H_{i}=\{\alpha e_{i}\mid\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Clearly
$H_{i}$ are mutually orthogonal closed subspace of $H$. Let $x\in H$.
Define $\alpha_{i}=\langle x,e_{i}\rangle$. For any finite subset
$J\subseteq I$, observe that $x=(x-\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}e_{j})+\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}e_{j}$
and $(x-\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}e_{j})$ is orthogonal to $\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}e_{j}$.
Therefore
\begin{eqnarray*}
||x||^{2} & = & ||x-\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}e_{j}||^{2}+||\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}e_{j}||^{2}\\
 & \geq & ||\sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}e_{j}||^{2}\\
 & = & \sum_{j\in J}\alpha_{j}^{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $J$ is arbitrary, it follows that $\sum_{i\in I}||\alpha_{i}e_{i}||^{2}\leq||x||^{2}<\infty$.
(Acually equality holds, but we do not need this). By the above result,
$\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_{i}e_{i}$ converges to $y$, for some $y\in H$.
From the construction of $y$, we can prove that, for each $i\in I$,
$\langle y,e_{i}\rangle=\alpha_{i}=\langle x,e_{i}\rangle$. Hence,
$\langle x-y,e_{i}\rangle=0$ for each $i$. Since $\{e_{i}\mid i\in I\}$
is a maximal orthonormal set, it follows that $x-y=0.$ That is, $x=\sum_{i\in I}\alpha_{i}e_{i}$.